# dropdownlist bind datatext field with a calculation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datatable with one column that is taken from DB

```
DataTable dt = ent.GetDataTable();
```

I am binding it to dropdownlist with

```
ddl.Datasource = dt;
ddl.datatextfield = "Test";
ddl.DataBind();
```

Now i want multiply each value in that column by 1000 and bind to dropdownlist. Is there a way to do this with out looping and changing each value.
I cannot modify the method or query that calls getdatatable() because these are predefined and used in many places.

Answer (score 1):

add `System.Linq` and ...

```
DataTable dt = ent.GetDataTable();

var a = from t in dt.AsEnumerable() select new
        {txt="test" , val=int.Parse(t[0])*1000} //0 = the index of your 
                                                      value column to multiply
ddl.Datasource = a;
ddl.DataBind();
```

in the aspx write

```
<asp:dropdownlist datatextfield="txt" datavalueField = "val" ...
```

Comment: isn't a linq query same as foreach loop?

Comment: @Sam1 he said `looping and changing each value` . Im not changing existing values im giving him a new data source.

Comment: I see, but he said without looping also you can achieve same thing with loop and then assign it to new datatable right?

Comment: the OP doesnt have the knowledge that he must iterate through items in order to change values. thats all